# Finding two scalar coefficients of the second derivative of a curve.

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a surface parametrized by $\phi(u,v)$ and a first fundamental form given by $$\begin{bmatrix}1+2u^2&1\\
1&1+4v^2\end{bmatrix}$$
Consider the curve $$c(t)=\phi(2,t^3)$$ let $c''=A\phi_u+B\phi_v+Cw$ where $w=\frac{\phi_u \times \phi_v}{||\phi_u \times \phi_v ||}$. I want to find $A,B$ in the point $\phi(2,1)$.

Of course, using the chain rule $$c''(t)=6t\phi_v(2,t^3)+9t^4\phi_{vv}(2,t^3)$$
And I don't know how to follow, if I could decompose $\phi_{vv}$ into a linear combination of $w$ and $\phi_u$ I could finish the problem but I don't know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\phi_{vv}$ as a combination of $\phi_u$, $\phi_v$ and $w$:
$$
 \phi_{vv} = D \phi_u + E \phi_v + F w,
$$
where $D$, $E$ and $F$ are functions.
Taking the inproduct of this expression with $\phi_u$ and $\phi_v$ respectively gives
$$
 \begin{align}
\tag{$\star$}
  \phi_{vv}\cdot \phi_u = D \phi_u\cdot\phi_u + E \phi_v \cdot \phi_u \\
  \phi_{vv}\cdot \phi_v = D \phi_u\cdot\phi_v + E \phi_v \cdot \phi_v.
 \end{align}
$$
Now, note that 
$$  
   \phi_{vv}\cdot \phi_u = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\phi_v\cdot \phi_u) - \phi_v\cdot \phi_{uv} = 0 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\phi_v\cdot\phi_v )= -\frac{1}{2}(8v) = -4v
$$ 
and
$$
   \phi_{vv}\cdot\phi_v = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial v} (\phi_v\cdot \phi_v) = 4v.
$$
So you can solve the system of equations $(\star)$ and obtain $D$ and $E$.

Remarks:

1. I guess it is a bit faster to use this approach immediately to the equation $c'' = A\phi_u + B\phi_v + C w$.
2. There is no way to determine $C$ (or $F$ in the calculation hereabove) with only information of the first fundamental form. One needs the 2nd fundamental form for that.

Comment: Applying your method to $c''$ I get to solve the system $\begin{cases}6t\phi_v·\phi_u(2,t^3)+9t^4\phi_{vv}·\phi_{u}(2,t^3)=A(1+2u^2)+B\\ 6t\phi_v·\phi_v(2,t^3)+9t^4\phi_{vv}·\phi_{v}(2,t^3)=A+B(1+4v^2) \end{cases}$ which gives $a=\frac{-221}{44},b=\frac{669}{44}$. Is this correct?